# Deleting the middle node of a dynamic linked-list, IF it exists

Tags: java, linked-list

For a programming challenge, I need to write a method that will delete the middle node of a linked list, only IF the list has an odd number of nodes. It should return the info in the middle node if it exists; and null otherwise.

For example, if the list is a->b->c->d->e, c is deleted. And if the list is a->b->c->d, nothing is deleted. The challenge prohibits the use of a counter variable or a boolean.

I know that it needs to be solved using only one loop. I know I should use a temporary node to progress through the loop, but I'm not sure how. I'm having trouble checking for the number of nodes in the list without using a counter, and figuring out how to move the pointer to the node in the middle.

```
public class DynamicNode {

  // the data in the node
  private Object info;

  // refers to the next node on the list
  private DynamicNode next;

  /**
   * Each time an object of type DynamicNode is instantiated, the constructor places the object
   * being stored in the node into the info field and "points" the next field to the next node in
   * the list.
   */
  public DynamicNode(Object x, DynamicNode n) {
    info = x;
    next = n;

  }

  /**
   * Extracts the object stored in the node.
   */
  public Object getInfo() {
    return info;
  }

  /**
   * "Points" to the node following the current node.
   */
  public DynamicNode getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  /**
   * Inserts the object into the node.
   */
  public void setInfo(Object x) {
    info = x;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the next field to the next node in the list.
   */
  public void setNext(DynamicNode n) {
    next = n;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return info.toString();
  }
}

class DynamicList {


  /**
   * Head of the list.
   */
  private DynamicNode head;

    /**
   * Instantiates a new list and initializes its head pointer to null.
   */
  public DynamicList() {
    head = null;
  }

  public DynamicList(DynamicNode head) {
    this.head = head;
  }

/**
   * Gets the head of the list.
   */
  public DynamicNode getList() {
    return head;
  }

// The problem!
public Object deleteMid() {

}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two pointers that start at head.

Move one pointer up one, the other up two in the list.

If the pointer that moves up twice EVER is NULL, then you don't have an odd numbered linked list.

If the pointer that moves up twice has its `next` field NULL, then the slower moving pointer will be at the middle node.

Try tracing this on a piece of a paper, with lists of varying length. You'll see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use two pointers.
Progress one of them one node each time and the other twice.
If you find out while trying to progress the faster pointer that you can’t move forward twice it means the list has an odd number of nodes. Return the slower pointers data. Otherwise, return null.